# Показывает что wifi без пароля

Tags: linux, wifi, manjaro, network-manager

У меня появилась такая проблема, что каогда я пытаюсь подключиться к определённой сети wifi не важно с какого адаптера, у меня она отображается без защиты и ноутбук не подключается к ней.
Система -Manjaro | NetworkManager | Сеть - dlink

oksana_____Infra__5_____130 Mbit/s___72______▂▄▆___WPA1 WPA2
dlink_______Infra__2_____0 Mbit/s_____65______▂▄▆___--
My-WiFi____Infra__3_____270 Mbit/s___65______▂▄▆___WPA2

На телефоне всё норм работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй удалить сохраненные настройки сети:

nmtui - изменить соединения - выбрать и удалить.

Comment: Не помогло, я уже пробовал до этого удалять чз nmcli. Сейчас его просто нет.

Comment: удали в /etc/NetworkManager если есть. если не поможет попробуй поставить линукс попроще. убунту например